# Does Flutter allow advanced window design?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, frameworks, cross-platform

I'm looking for a cross-platform framework that would allow me to have a very customized window (no title bar, components partially outside of the main frame).

As Flutter for Desktop app seems at its early stage right now, it's hard to get the info and to know what it is capable of. So I don't find answers to my question.

I know that someone released a feature that allows to get rid of the window bars but it's not enough for what I need.

Basically, the interface that looks the most like what I need is the one from CleanMyMac (MacPaw), which goes beyond the classical rectangle window.

[image]

If Flutter isn't there yet, do you know any other cross-platform that would do just that ?

Electron.js seems a dead end (Mac App Store rejects it, not efficient, heavy,...).
Neutralino.js seems like improved Electron but might be a vaporware at this stage.
Proton Native seems engaging but I doubt it allows what I need at this point.
React Native seems more mobile oriented than Desktop.

So, I'm pretty stuck and don't know what options I have and what would fit the bill.

PS: AFAIK, CleanMyMac is using Swift so it's not cross-platform (at this point in time).

Thanks for your input.

Comment: desktop support is in stable flutter release v2.0 (now as pre-release) and will be at final stage in few months this year

Comment: Thanks but what about my question:  Is flutter able at this point to handle my requirements ? All interfaces I've seen so far are classical. And I didn't read anything that says they are customizable.

Comment: there are couple of web demos like https://flutterplasma.dev/ or https://flutter.github.io/samples/#

Comment: Did you find your answer, perhaps you tried with Flutter?

Comment: Sorry for my very late answer (I haven't come back here for a while). No I haven't found any solution, sorry.